# A Semi-Transparent Border in CSS - Tumblr Theme Coding

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm trying to make the sidebar for my theme match the main content, in that there's a solid background with a transparent border. I can make them work individually, but when I try to do both it doesn't work right. Here's the snipet of code that's been causing the problem:

```
#sidebar {
     width: 300px; 
    background-color: #A3A3CC;
    /*border-style: solid; border-width: 15px; border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 60px;
    top: 90px; 
    height: 490px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

I am aware that the border code is noted out, and that's because the border code and the background color code work fine individually, but when I have both at the same time, I get [this](http://s10.postimg.org/cl917j2t5/both_make_a_problem.png).

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I just want to have a semi-transparent background under  a solid one to make a nice border effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a box-shadow instead of a border.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZjtY/1/)

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #A3A3CC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
    left: 60px;
    top: 90px;
    height: 490px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much. Would you happen to know how to put a third box on top in gray?

Comment: You can have multiple box-shadows but it will depend on your actual design. The box-shadow will always be on the outside of any border - http://jsfiddle.net/8ZjtY/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since the border is rendered on top of the background of the div, they are stacking and not giving you what you want. You could wrap another div around it, and use that as your border:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6uXU/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="outer"><div id="sidebar"> </div></div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: #A3A3CC;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 490px;
}
#outer{
    padding:15px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
    left: 60px;
    top: 90px; 
}
```